# read only TMOUT variable – workaround to disable automatically exit shell when there is no activity

Tags: bash, environment-variables, readonly, timeout

We have here a read only Bash variable. I am not allowed to unset that variable.

```
$ echo $TMOUT
1800
```

As a workaround I wrote those lines (that my session don't exit)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$|++;
while (1) { print "\e[0n"; sleep 120; }
```

Is there an official package (rpm) that does similar (like above Perl code) in a CentOS7/RHEL7 repository? I don't like to open up a vim editor, I wish a command.

Comment: Usual solution to this is just run `cat` when stepping away from your session.  And then ^C it on your return.

Comment: I imposed a similar rule because I had people in my team that left terminals open for weeks in a row. Whilst I do agree 1800 is kinda of low, it must be there for some reason. People tend to notice deviations to the usual...yours sessions will stand out like a sore thumb.

Comment: when it's read-only, type:
`exec env TMOUT=0 bash`

Comment: I've found that simply [not closing the terminal on exit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/630698/how-can-i-keep-the-gnome-terminal-open-after-a-program-closes) works around most of the reasons I hate this "feature". Trying to remember to `cat` is just setting yourself up to fail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can issue perl commands from the command line...

`perl -e '$|++; while (1) { print "\e[0n"; sleep 120; }'`

or you could do the same in shell (a `sh`/`bash` example):

`while sleep 120; do printf '\33[0n'; done`

Or you could use `watch`:

`watch -n 120 printf '\33[0n'`

Comment: what is `printf '\33[0n'`? i know what the command line `printf` is. but what is being printed?

Comment: `\33` is shorthand for the escape key `<esc>[0n` is not a known ANSI escape code, I imagine it was a typo and should of been `<esc>[0m` which resets the terminal colour for apps/terminals/tty's that support ANSI escape codes.

Answer (score 23):

Add this to the start of your .bash_profile ?

```
if [ ! -z "$TMOUT" ]; then
  env -i bash --init-file ~/.bash_profile
fi
```

Beware the wrath of the sysadmins if you leave a gazillion old sessions running as a result of defeating their timeout rulings.

Comment: This is truly EVIL!

Comment: The -i argument wipes out the environment. You can be more specific and only unset a single variable like so: env -u TMOUT bash --init-file ~/.bash_profile

Comment: I use `--norc` to ignore the system settings.

Answer (score 10):

Here is the thing,
When the session variable is **"Read Only"** you have to replace the current shell process with the command by **"exec"**
**So, the Answer to your question is:**

```
$> exec env TMOUT=0 bash
```

But I recommend setting a higher timeout value

```
$> exec env TMOUT=3600 bash
```

Comment: If I add `exec env TMOUT=0 bash` to `.bashrc`, is it going to work in the same way?

Answer (score 4):

I my case, it is defined in /etc/profile.d/bash_autologout.sh:

```
TMOUT=1800
readonly TMOUT
export TMOUT
```

To find it, I did:

```
sudo find /etc/ -name "*" | xargs sudo grep "TMOUT" 2>&1 | grep -v "filter..."
```

Comment: I have `/etc/bash.bashrc`

Answer (score 0):

export TMOUT=0

top

You will have some activity and your session will stay and you could see how long it runs.

Answer (score -1):

Why aren't you switching to non-interactive session?

```
# TMOUT=0
-bash: TMOUT: readonly variable
# unset TMOUT
-bash: unset: TMOUT: cannot unset: readonly variable
# su
# export TMOUT=10
# unset TMOUT
#
```

Comment: I'm not a superuser.